# --remote in openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to configure openvpn.
As I read there is an option "--remote".
It says the client the IP address of server to connect.
Now my question is, is it possible to use "--remote" in server config so I can restrict client that wants to connect to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `--remote` option cannot be used to filter connections to the server. This should be implemented by a firewall on the server.